# In PostMan how do i get number of records (count) of xml response?

Tags: javascript, xml, npm, postman

Hi I am trying to do for XML response length not able to do it please find below error i am getting..

"There was an error in evaluating the test script:  ReferenceError: xml2json is not defined"
my script is as below:

```
var myData = xml2json(responseBody);
console.log(responseBody);
var body = JSON.parse(myData);
tests["Response Count is:  " + myData.markers && myData.markers.length] = true;
```

could you please let me know is there any other way to get xml response count??
Also I have used URL:  format=JSON but getting null value printed in the console or undefined.

Comment: you may try xml2Json (uppercase J) ... and have a look here : https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox

Comment: I did tried with upper case too but no luck...xml2Json, XML2JSON, XML2Json all possible ways.

Comment: Can you show us your responseBody ?

Comment: hitting the services <endpointurl>?Starttime=2017-10-19T11:30&endtime=2017-10-19T11:45&format=JSON Please find below structure like this I am getting 1000+ records, using at the end as format=JSON for getting JSONresponse <?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers><messages><code>100</code>message>Successful</message></messages><tag2><tag3><AbcID>2e</AbcIDID><lay>XX</lay><timestamp><absolute>XX</absolute></timestamp><container></container><cut><legacyIds><CompId>59</ComId></legacyIds><title>T</title><author>X</author><IOId>123</IOId></cut></tag3>/likeabovegetting 1000records<tag3></tag3></tag2></markers>

Answer (score 0):

Came across this in search of a solution myself. This worked for me for Postman 10.12.13 with Cheerio. Counting objects from an S3 bucket in AWS. The XML is `ListBucketResult>Contents`.

```
var xml = cheerio.load(pm.response.text());
console.log('xml nodes: ' + xml('Contents').length);
```